# Operar los elementos de dos array en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Mi contexto es un cajero el cual le ingresas el dinero deseado y te lo da siempre y cuando la cantidad ingresada pueda ser realizada con los billetes disponibles (en mi caso puse billetes de mi país, Uruguay), tengo dos array "caja" y "entregados": en caja tengo billetes los cuales son instancias de la clase con el mismo nombre y en entregados tengo los billetes que el se le den al usuario; tengo una parte en la que se muestra cuanto dinero disponible tiene el cajero. Se me ocurrió que podría sumar los billetes de entregados, sumar los de caja y luego hacer la resta pero, cuando entrego billetes no los elimino de caja (no se como hacerlo); acá mi duda es como eliminar los billetes que se den del array caja. Si a alguien se le ocurre una forma mas sencilla u optima de hacer lo que quiero es bienvenida su colaboración.

```js
class Billete {
    
    constructor(valor, cantidad) {
        this.valor = valor;
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
        this.imagen = new Image();
        this.imagen.src = imagenes[this.valor];
    }
}

let imagenes = [];
imagenes[20] = "img/20.png";
imagenes[50] = "img/50.png";
imagenes[100] = "img/100.png";
imagenes[200] = "img/200.png";
imagenes[500] = "img/500.png";
imagenes[1000] = "img/1000.png";
imagenes[2000] = "img/2000.png";

let caja = [];
let entregado = [];
let dinero = 0;
let div = 0;
let papeles = 0;
let total = 0;
let saldo = document.getElementById("saldo");
let resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");
let b = document.getElementById("extraer");

function entregarDinero() {
    let t = document.getElementById("dinero");
    dinero = t.value;

    for(let bi of caja) {

        if(dinero > 0){
            div = Math.floor(dinero / bi.valor);
            
            if(div > bi.cantidad) {
                papeles = bi.cantidad;
            } else {
                papeles = div;
            }
            entregado.push( new Billete(bi.valor, papeles));
            dinero -= (bi.valor * papeles);
        }
    }

    if(dinero > 0) {
        resultado.innerHTML = "En este cajero no hay tanto dinero.";
    } else {
        for(let e of entregado) {
            if(e.cantidad > 0) {
                resultado.innerHTML += e.cantidad + " billetes de $" + e.valor + " " + "<br/>";
                for(let i = 0; i < e.cantidad; i++){
                    resultado.innerHTML += "<img src=" + e.imagen.src + " />";
                }
                resultado.innerHTML += "<br/>";
                resultado.innerHTML += "<br/>"; 
            }
        }
        resultado.innerHTML += "<hr/>"; 
    };
}

function verSaldo() {
    for(let c of caja) {
        total += (c.valor * c.cantidad);
    }
    saldo.innerHTML = "El saldo del cajero es: " + total;
}

caja.push(new Billete(2000, 50));
caja.push(new Billete(1000, 100));
caja.push(new Billete(500, 200));
caja.push(new Billete(200, 500));
caja.push(new Billete(100, 1000));
caja.push(new Billete(50, 2000));
caja.push(new Billete(20, 5000));

verSaldo();
b.addEventListener("click", entregarDinero);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cajero Automático</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <p id="saldo"></p>
    <p>
        <img src="img/cajero.gif">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="number" id="dinero" min="0" />
        <input type="button" id="extraer" value="Extraer" />
    </p>
    <p id="resultado"></p>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para eliminar de un array prueba usar el método filter de los arrays, busca un tutorial en Youtube, o mejor aún en la documentación de Mozilla, te explico brevemente, con el map vas recorriendo uno por uno los elementos de un array, retornas en cada iteración  los elementos que quieras conservar y el que quieres eliminar pasas de el. El resultado un array con los billetes que te quedan. También creo que hay un función llamada split que sirve para eso.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte Emmanuel, había leído que esos métodos servían pero, pesé que quizás había otra forma mas practica u optima de hacer lo mismo. Me pongo a leer la documentación (casi siempre me parece mejor leer documentación que ver tutos jaja).